# Sorting the date column incorrectly in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure to generate report using the SQL Server Reporting Services. Stored Procedure returns results and has one date column.

Now i would like to display the date in Aug 5 2009, 11:20:AM format instead of showing MM/DD/YYYY so i have cast the date as follows in select query inside the Stored Procedure [select col1, col2, cast(datecol as varchar(max)  ...)]. This has helped me get the date displayed in correct format i wanted but the columns are getting sort as per text(A-Z) instead of the date.

Can someone tell me what should i do so that i am able to get the date in expected format and still be able to sort the column like its Date not String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the data as a date, and use reporting services `Format` method to change the way it is displayed.

See [this thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic290724-150-3.aspx) for description of the parameters to use

So you'll end up using something like this expression:

```
=Format(Fields!MyDateField,"MMM d yyyy, HH:mm tt")
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes found one more like this FormatDateTime() Function. But Format() surely looks much better :)

Comment: @Anil - `FormatDateTime` takes some preset formats like `ShortDate`, whereas `Format` allows fine control over the output.

Comment: This is a good answer but I had to make a slight amendment to counter an error.  Updated as follows =Format(Fields!MyDateField.Value,"MMM d yyyy, HH:mm tt")

Answer (score 2):

`=CDate(Fields!MyDateField.Value)`

The value returned in your report are a "String", CDate converts this string value to a Date type. Doing that possible the sort by this column as Date type correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to be up voted you should explain your answer.